# JQuery Mobile - Select Menu - option too long

Tags: jquery

I have a selectmenu like this:

```
 $("#Menu").empty();
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      $("#Menu").append("<option value=\"" + data[i].id + "\">" + data[i].description + "</option>");
    }
    $("#Menu").selectmenu('refresh');
```

but the `data[i].description` are too long, so the select is cut and the option isn't shown entire.

Any Suggestion??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could show a list of radiobuttons to allow the user to make a selection. This way you can display all the description text as needed.

See the documentation here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-radiobuttons.html.